# Fitting word for "subject to physics" or possibly "subject to laws"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a fitting word that means "subject to physics" or possibly "subject to laws"? It seems to me that I must have read such a word somewhere but I simply can't dredge one up.

Ex:
Any passengers on a star ship could be killed instantly, mashed to a a pulp, by inertial forces because the ship itself is [an] [thing which is subject to physical laws]

Comment: A thing can be said to be physical if it is subject to physical laws. Water is physical, and rocks are physical objects. Things that are not subject to physical laws (like love, religion, and unicorns) are said to be nonphysical.

Comment: True. For some reason, that does not have the connotation my brain is grasping for. Perhaps "subject to regulation" or "subject to being subjected to" would clarify my meaning (or perhaps not).

Comment: I'm not clear on what OP wants his target word to mean, but it seems to me the subject is perhaps being muddied by the "figurative" expression ***subject to** [the **laws** of] physics*.  It seems to me that in most contexts it's more useful to say physical phenomena ***reflect*** or ***manifest*** the laws of physics. They have no "wish" to do otherwise, so they're not really "constrained" or "limited" by the principles we anthropomorphise as "laws".

Comment: A fair criticism. For semantic purposes can we allow me to anthropomorphize it? Although you may have put me on a better track for my current project.

Comment: If we had some example of what you're talking about it might help; vague descriptions are not conducive to precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Corporeal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corporeal)** might fit.

> of a material nature; physical

Also, Descartes suggested this many years ago in [Res Extensa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Res_extensa):

> Res extensa (often translated "**corporeal substance**" by Descartes) is one of the three substances described by René Descartes in his Cartesian ontology, alongside res cogitans and God.
>
> Translated from Latin, "res extensa" means "extended thing". In Descartes' substance-attribute-mode ontology, extension is the primary attribute of corporeal substance. Sometimes referred to as "radical dualism."

From the book "Descartes and the Metaphysics of Sensory Perception" *By Joseph Wook Hwang*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All of the things I can think of are adjectives, and so to make them nouns you would add 'thing' or 'entity' or something similar. Possible words are:

- "Physical" thing or entity
- "Material" thing or entity (literally meaning composed of matter)

"Because the ship is material" (or physical) would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[matter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matter)."

> Any passengers on a starship could be killed instantly, mashed to a a pulp by inertial forces, because the ship itself is **[matter](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~mclennan/Classes/UH348/Intro-IIA.html)** (or material) i.e. subject to the laws of physics.

Answer (score -2):

**"In Reality"** or **"In Fact"** since everything is subject to those laws that isn't imaginary.

Comment: Perhaps my grammar was confusing. Ill attempt a re-edit.

Comment: Immaterial things can be real.